# Dynamically changing the template parameters of a class

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to make it ?

For instance, consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> class A {
public:
  void print() {
    T var;
    cout << sizeof(var) << endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  A<int>* c = new A<int>;
  c->print();

  A<char>* d = reinterpret_cast<A<char>*>(c);
  d->print();
}
```

Is there a "danger" with this kind of pratice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this would invoke undefined behaviour.  `A<char>` and `A<int>` are entirely unrelated types.  So it's no different to reinterpret-casting as a `B`.

In practice, it will probably work (at least for something this simple).  But that doesn't mean that you can rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a "danger" with this kind of pratice ?

This is an **undefined behavior**, as you are converting a pointer to a different type and then calling a function.
Remember that `A<int>` and `A<char>` are different types; don't get confused from the same name `A`.

[Here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#conversion) is a good related article from Bjarne Stroustrup's web page.